# Social media Login using keycloak

Tags: angularjs, facebook, twitter, google-plus, keycloak

We have angular js integrated with keycloak services. When the person logins to our application, we enable social media login also.
But after login, we would like to know which social media the user used for login.

Is it possible by anyways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a new user attribute with authentication provider info.  In every identity provider, add a "hardcore attribute" with a provider name.
Next, take this value from your app to know what social network was used.